# check a radio button based on input focus

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to check a radio button when a user click on the input field.  I can not figure out how to identify the radio button.  The below code does nothing...

```js
 $(function() {
   $('.searchInput').focus(function() {
     $(this).prev('.radio').find(':radio').prop('checked', true);

   });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table align='left' width='100%' class='searchWindow'>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type='radio' class='radio' name='searchType' value='byUser'>
      <th>By User</th>
      <td colspan='2'>
        <input type='text' id='user' size='32' class='searchInput'>
      </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type='radio' class='radio' name='searchType' value='byDate'>
      <th width='20%'>By Date</th>
      <td width='35%'>
        <input type='text' id='beg' size='8' placeholder='Begin Date' class='searchInput'>
      </td>
      <td width='35%'>
        <input type='text' id='end' size='8' placeholder='End Date' class='searchInput'>
      </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type='radio' id='ff' name='searchType' class='radio' value='bySubject'>
      <th>By Subject</th>
      <td colspan='2'>
        <input type='text' id='subject' size='32' class='searchInput'>
      </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using wrong methods. Use `closest('tr')` to find ancestor `tr` and then `find(':radio')` to find `radio` button in it.

```
$(this).closest('tr').find(':radio').prop('checked', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

DOM navigation is the key.

You need to think about the "common container" for a pair if inputs - which in this case, is the `tr` row.

Then, once you identify the common container, you can then do a `find` the desired input.

This is best accomplished using [closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to find the nearest `tr` ancestor, and then [find](https://api.jquery.com/find/)

This would look like so:

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('input.radio').prop('checked', true);
```